# Why are the colors of my Mandelbrot set crooked looking and not nice and symmetric?

Tags: java, javafx, mandelbrot

I am wondering why is the background of my Mandelbrot set not as nice as the background on the other picture. Also, why does the Mandelbrot set still show up if I set the number 4 in the if statement of iterationChecker to any other number bigger than 4?

Mandelbrot set, and the background looks crooked:

[image: crooked]

I want the background to look like this:

[image: desire]

Comment: You have a typo in your `while` loop condition in `iterationChecker(...)`. (Should be `zi * zi`, not `zi + zi`.)

Answer (score 5):

The iteration count is slightly off because of a typo in the condition for counting iterations to escape:

```
public int iterationChecker(double cr, double ci) {
    int iterationsOfZ = 0;
    double zr = 0.0;
    double zi = 0.0;

    //while (iterationsOfZ < maximumIterations && (zr * zr) + (zi + zi) < 4){

    while (iterationsOfZ < maximumIterations && (zr * zr) + (zi * zi) < 4){
        double oldZr = zr;
        zr = (zr * zr) - (zi * zi) + cr;
        zi = 2 * (oldZr * zi) + ci;
        iterationsOfZ++;
    }
    return iterationsOfZ;
}
```

> Also, why does the Mandelbrot set still show up if I set the number 4 in the if statement of iterationChecker to any other number bigger than 4?

A point `c` is considered to be in the Mandelbrot set if the sequence defined by `z(n+1) = z(n)^2 + c` (with `z(0)=0`) is bounded for all `n`.

It's easy enough to prove that if `|c|>2` then `c` is not in the Mandelbrot set, and for `|c|<=2`, that if `|z(n)| > 2` for any n, then the sequence `z(n)` is unbounded, and hence if `|z(n)| > 2` (i.e. `|z|^2=zr^2+zi^2 > 4`) then `c` is not in the Mandelbrot set.

So the strategy is to iterate `z -> z^2 + c`, and if `|z|^2>4` at any point conclude `z` is not in the Mandelbrot set. Of course, if you choose any `k>4`, then if `|z|^2 > k`, then it's also true that `|z|^2 > 4`, and `z` is not in the Mandelbrot set.

Finding `z` with `|z|^2 > 4` is called "escaping", and the number of iterations until escape determines the color. If you reach some maximum number of iterations (you chose 50) without escaping, then you assume `c` is "close to" or inside the Mandelbrot set and color it black.

So changing the escape level to another number bigger than 4 might change the colors, but it will not change it by much: the absolute value of `|z(n)|` grows as `n^2` from that point. So you would have to increase the escape threshold by a lot to make a difference of more than 1 or 2 in the time to escape.